# How to properly parse Result Array from database with Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have codeigniter application which fetches data from database and this data is manipulated by Jquery. Result array from database used to look like this:

```
 { "result":[
    {"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}] }
```

And I use to parse it using code below:

```
$.get("index.php/getResult",{f_name: $('#fn').val()} ,function(data) {
    var list= "";
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        if (index > 0) {list;}
        list+= element.name;
    });
    $('#myid').html(list);
},"json");
```

My result array has changed to the format below, how can I parse it now? Any help is appreciated.

```
{
"count": 8,
"result":[
{"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to parse anything:

```
$.get("index.php/getResult",{f_name: $('#fn').val()} ,function(data) 
{
    alert(data.count);

    for(var i=0; i< data.result.length; i++)
    {
        alert(data.result[i].name + " " + data.result[i].surname);
        // etc.
    }
    // etc.

},"json");
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using json (what means **J** ava **S** cript- **O** bject- **N** otation) you can use this object like any ohter JavaScript object. So you can access `result[0].name` for example. For debugging i recommend to use **Firebug** Add-On for Firefox or **Chrome Webdevelopertool**. In both you can write `console.log(data)` or `console.log(result[0].name)` for example and view your object in console-tab.